# How to load vendor files with webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webpack, fullpage.js

I'm using this package via npm:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

If I do a `require('fullpage.js')` - it works fine.

However, I need to use some extensions:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#use-extensions

Therefore I need to use `jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js` located in `node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/`

Since this is defined in the `package.json` of `fullpage.js:`

```
// This is the fill I will get with my require.
"main": "dist/jquery.fullpage.js"
```

How can I tell webpack to use another (or multiple other) files?

Comment: can you update the question with your webpack config?

Answer (score 0):

You can use vendor entry point with webpack config.

```
entry: {
    main: "./main",
    vendor: ["node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js", "...some..other--lib"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

How do I reference the entry point? My main .js file is located in /resources/assets/js/app.js (I'm using Laravel 5.3).

Can't seem to make it eat any path.

Answer (score 0):

If `require('fullpage.js')` works, you can use this approach:

```
require('fullpage.js');
require('fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js'):
```